# plink - PuTTY's command line tool or genome association analysis toolset?

Tags: support, tags

The tag [plink](/questions/tagged/plink) is currently ambigous - while the tag wiki states it's for the [putty](/questions/tagged/putty) component, there are some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9863208) which instead refer to a [genome association analysis toolset](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/). What about one of the following:

1. rename the current [putty](/questions/tagged/putty) [plink](/questions/tagged/plink) tag to [putty-plink](/questions/tagged/putty-plink) and leave [plink](/questions/tagged/plink) for the genome tool
2. leave [plink](/questions/tagged/plink) as it is and declare the genome tool questions off-topic - there's http://biology.stackexchange.com, though their [faq](https://biology.stackexchange.com/faq) currently doesn't clearly state whether software questions are on-topic (maybe as a subset of "questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory")

Comment: I removed my answer, but to answer your last question, No, I'd not say that the Genome software is on topic on SO.

Comment: It's more appropriate on biostars.org but its not part of the stackexchange network.